# Displaying Database Information in TextBox From Another Form Using DataGridView

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to display information (User Comment) from my MySQL database into a textbox in another form. I am using a datagridview to select the UID to identify which user the comment is for. My code is in the load event of the Comment form, like so...

```
    try
        {
            // Check if a row is selected.
            string cRow = admin.gridClients.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string Query = "SELECT Admin_Com FROM cpr_clients WHERE Client_ID='" + cRow + "';";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect);
            MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                txtAdminCom.Text = myReader["Admin_Com"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Edit: I have updated my code. The code only retrieves the comment of the first row in the datagridview even if I have selected another row.

Comment: are you passing current form object as a parameter in constructor of another form?

Comment: In your code above, where is `admin` declared and what is the modifier scope of `gridClients`?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner admin is delclared as an instance in the class of the current form and the scope is set to Public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely your problem is there is no `CurrentRow` on your source (`admin.gridClients`) grid view. This will cause attempting to access `.Cells` to throw the error you are getting because `CurrentRow == null`.

Since you *only* need this value to identify the Id in the `frmAdminComment`, read the value in your source form and then pass it the constructor of `frmAdminComment`:

```
private string _id;

public frmAdminComment(string id)
{
    // Initialization code you already have.

    // Set the Id for this instance.
    _id = id;
}
```

Now reference the `_id` variable in your load method:

```
string Query = "SELECT Admin_Com FROM cpr_clients WHERE Client_ID='" + _id + "';";
```

This puts the burden of checking for a valid value in the `admin` object which is creating `frmAdminComment`.

```
// In the "admin" object.
if (gridClients.CurrentRow == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No CurrentRow is set in the source grid.");
    return;
}
else
{
    // CurrentRow is set - safe to reference it.
    var adminComment = new frmAdminComment(gridClients.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    adminComment.Show();
}
```

You may want to consider using the `SelectedRows` property instead. It would work like this:

```
// Check if a row is selected.
// In the "admin" object.
if (gridClients.SelectedRows.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No rows selected in the source grid.");
}
else
{
    // CurrentRow is set - safe to reference it.
    var adminComment = new frmAdminComment(gridClients.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    adminComment.Show();
}
```

Note that if you use `SelectedRows` then you may want to set the properties on `gridClients` to allow only a single row to be selected at one time with the selection mode set to FullRowSelect.

Comment: I have added the full condition to the beginning of the function but it still only returns the MessageBox so it is still null

Comment: @TobyCook - Right. If you see the message box then it means `CurrentRow` is null/not set in `admin.gridClients`. I updated the answer to include checking this prior to creating your `frmAdminComment` object so the user is alerted they need to pick a row.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but as I am using ContextMenuStrip as the method of viewing the comment it means there would already be a row selected prior to the form opening. Sorry if I am over complicating this

Comment: @TobyCook - No necessarily. If your context menu is invoked with a right-click then it does not mean the respective row is selected. Just for the sake of testing, do a left-click (which will select the row) _before_ invoking your context menu and see if the result is different.

Comment: I tried what you said and the result is the same as before. I can upload my source to pastebin if needed?

Comment: @TobyCook - You may want to try the `SelectedRow` property instead. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: Now the index is out of range for `admin.gridClients.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();` so I am assuming it is the SelectedRows?

Comment: @TobyCook - Try changing the properties of the `gridClients` for selection mode and set to FullRowSelection. WHen this is set the entire row will be selected when you click a cell.

Comment: @TobyCook - Is this the only value you need to get from `admin.gridClients.CurrentRow` for use in `frmAdminComment`?

Comment: It's the value of the cell I need as I'm using it to identify which user the comment is for

Comment: @TobyCook - I updated the answer to suggest an alternate design.

Comment: Slight longer load time but it works. Thank you for your time, Jason!